# Getting already selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery

By using following code I am getting the selected text's startindex and the selected text itself. I am storing them in a local database. I am changing the selected text background color to yellow.

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var sel = getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(mainDiv);

var selectedText = window.getSelection();

location.href =  selectedText + '*' + sel.start; // this is to call iOS function.

var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
span.setAttribute("id", sel.start);
range.surroundContents(span);
```

Now, I am doing something else, and again I come back to same page. Here now I want to show previously selected text as highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Use Rangy , nothing beats it , does exactly what your trying

[Rangy](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=http://code.google.com/p/rangy/&ei=ATQaUdK_AsnorQeXi4DwDg&usg=AFQjCNGaVUHBkBJ67kgi-XhKZlK7jedZZg&bvm=bv.42261806,d.bmk)

Have a look at this [demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/index.html)